# unable to send email using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

```
   // this is my code
//unable to send email using sendgrid
// finding email from body
    exports.signUp=async (req,res)=>{
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        if(userExists){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:"eamil is already taken"
            })
        }
        const token = jwt.sign(req.body, process.env.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,{expiresIn:'20m'})
        const emailSend = {
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
            to: req.body.email,
            subject:`Acoount activation link`,
            html:`
                <p> Please click the following link to activate</p>
    
                <a>http://localhost:8000/api/auth/activate/${token}</a>
            `
        }
        sgMail.send(emailSend).then(sent=>{
            return res.status(200).json({
                message:'email has been sent to you emailid'
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
    
    
    
   // this is error am getting
// am getting this error
```

> ResponseError: Forbidden
> at D:\node-projects\ecom\node_modules@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:146:29
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
> code: 403,
> response: {
> headers: {
> server: 'nginx',
> date: 'Thu, 07 Jan 2021 11:55:26 GMT',
> 'content-type': 'application/json',
> 'content-length': '281',
> connection: 'close',
> 'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
> 'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
> 'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
> 'access-control-max-age': '600',
> 'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html'
> },
> body: { errors: [Array] }
> }
> }

Comment: Why? subject:`Acoount activation link` and not subject:'Acoount activation link', the quotes I mean

Comment: How do you setup the sengrid service? Can you add the implementation for the setup. In this example the `sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);` is missing. refer to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail#quick-start-hello-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log said it failed because it received a Forbidden html response.
Try to check if you have set your `Sender Authentication` in your SendGrid Settings.
Only if you've set this done, you can send your email out.

References: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify your single sender email for this error to be resolved